# GET vs POST API for validating docker image is allowed

Tags: python, rest, api, microservices

Unsure of whether to use a GET or POST for this situation. I'm creating an API that will return whether a docker image is compliant or not. What would be the better approach?

Scenario 1:

```
GET: https://<hostname>/api/checkImage?image=nginx:latest
```

Scenario 2

```
GET: https://<hostname>/api/checkImage/nginx:latest
```

Scenario 3

```
POST: https://<hostname>/api/checkImage
Payload: {"image": "nginx"}
```

Obviously would need to url encode the colon, but all of the above scenarios would return:
`{"allowed": false}`

Comment: GET is for retrieving information about a thing.  POST is for creating, changing state, or saving data

Answer (score 0):

The important semantic concept to understand is [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only
>
> Of the request methods defined by this specification, the GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, and TRACE methods are defined to be safe.

So in your case, the *resource* is something like "the compliance report for the image"; and the GET request asks that the server provide the current representation of the report.  The server might choose to provide a previously cached representation, or it might generate a new compliance report and return that -- but those are implementation details unrelated to the semantics of the request.

On the other hand, if we want the server to update its representation of the resource to something more recent, then we would likely use POST, rather than GET, because we're trying to induce a change and we don't want a general-purpose cache to return a stale representation of the report.

From the perspective of the client, it might look like

```
GET /api/checkImage?image=nginx:latest

Oh, this representation is too old, I need something recent

POST /api/checkImage?image=nginx:latest
```